# table of content in persian language (the number is right to left)

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, right-to-left, xepersian, persian

I use  code

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{ \bfseries   \filleft\Huge}{ \chaptername\  \arabic \LTR{ \thechapter} }{6pt}{\bfseries\filleft}
```

to write a table of content. in the table have

[image]

but I  like to have

فصل 3

1.3

2.3

1.2.3

I use ubuntu and texlive 2019.
I read this question [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269707/how-to-reverse-section-numbering-for-right-to-left-languages)

but not work.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Salaam, Fatemeh. It would be nice if you could include a minimal working example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Answer (score 0):

Use these codes:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\@SepMark\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter\@SepMark\arabic{section}\@SepMark\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsection\@SepMark\arabic{paragraph}\@SepMark}
\makeatother
%\SepMark{-}  
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{فصل}
\section{بخش دوم}
\section{بخش اول}
\subsection{زیر بخش اول}
\paragraph{پارگراف}
\chapter{فصل}
\section{بخش دوم}
\subsection{زیر بخش دوم}
\paragraph{پارگراف}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Good luck.